# Troubles with a piechart applet

Tags: java, applet, japplet

Alright the deal is I am trying to use the drawPie method to create my pie chart in an applet. After attempting google searches I find multiple tutorials that explain part of the process but not all of it. While trying to knit together partial information I am not getting the results I want.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;

    import javax.swing.JApplet;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class JLW_PieApplet extends JApplet {

class PieData extends JComponent {
    PieValue[] slices = new PieValue[4];

    PieData() {
        slices[0] = new PieValue(35, Color.red);
        slices[1] = new PieValue(33, Color.green);
        slices[2] = new PieValue(20, Color.pink);
        slices[3] = new PieValue(12, Color.blue);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        drawPie((Graphics2D)g, getBounds(), slices);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Where's your `drawPie(...)` method?

Comment: He just pasted a piece of code copied from http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/Pie.html, I guess the reason can be anything at this point.

Comment: "I am not getting the results I want." What are the results you are getting and how do they differ from what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `PieData` component within your applet but you never add it, so you need to add it in `init` and bring in `drawPie` from your [link](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/Pie.html) above:

```
public class JLW_PieApplet extends JApplet {

   public void init() {
      add(new PieData());
   }

   class PieData extends JComponent {
      PieValue[] slices = new PieValue[4];

      PieData() {
         slices[0] = ...
      }

      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         drawPie((Graphics2D) g, getBounds(), slices);
      }

      public void drawPie(Graphics2D g, Rectangle area, PieValue[] slices) {
      ...
```

Comment: That's a fair point, but given the fact that we're missing so much of the code, it could also be a layout issue, or a problem with the drawPie method it self, or the fact that he fails to call super.paint(g) :P

Comment: Given the code presented + the link, it will work by adding this method. :)

Comment: No doubt it will "work", but that doesn't change the fact that it is still fundamentally flawed (the question, not the answer)

Comment: Thank you Reimeus. The answers you provided both initially and in your revisions were helpful. I still end up doing some of the leg work my own which is part of the point but you at least pointed me in the right direction without complaining about it not being an ideal textbook question.

Answer (score 1):

Ther isn't such method in Swing called drawPie. Without the contents of this method, we have no idea of how to help you

Try having a read through [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and have a look at [Ellipse2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) in particular

The other problem I can see is you don't call `super.paint(g)` in your paint method.  This is VERY, VERY, VERY important

Comment: He shouldn't even be overriding `paint(...)` but rather `paintComponent(...)`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no argument there